# Flutter Crypto App working with full functionality on Emulator & physical device but after rolling out to app store many functionalities are missing

Tags: flutter, api, flutter-dependencies, bitcoin, coingecko

I have built a Crypto App with API from https://api.coingecko.com/api/...

This App works fine when on Emulator or Physical Device but after it is rolled out for production in Play Store, many functionalities are missing from the App (the whole API).

Play Store link : com.codoweb.cryptorealtime

Here are some snapshots for your better understanding -

[image: App Running in Emulator/Physical Device]

[image: App Running after Downloading from Play Store]

What do I do ? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive you missed to add internet permission in the manifest

```dart
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <application ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: Yes you are right ! I missed it.. Thank You very much